# Resolve project assembly references from nuget packages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, assembly-references

I accidentally deleted all the project references after rebuilding a project.
The nuget package manager restored the *packages* folder, but all the packages' assemblies are not referred to from the project  (Project->References).

How do I add all nuget packages' assemblies as project references?

Comment: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never knew, but when the command `update-package -reinstall` is called parameterless, it would update all the packages.

Thanks for Matt for his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114280/resolve-project-assembly-references-from-nuget-packages?noredirect=1#comment46462822_29114280).